# Edge addition complexity in planar graph?

Tags: complexity-theory, graph-theory, planar-graph

I created a program that adds edges between vertices. The goal is to add as many edges as possible without crossing them(ie Planar graph). What is the complexity?

Attempt: Since I used depth first search I think it is O(n+m) where n is node and m is edge.

Also, if we plot the number of edges as a function of n what is it going to look like?

(* I'm re posting the question since noone answered it the last time *)

Comment: How can someone tell you the complexity of your algorithm when you don't say how the algorithm works?